# No module named 'geopy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, miniconda, geopy

I am trying to install geopy in a virtual environment created by miniconda. When I do `pip install geopy`, it gives me this:

```
(finalenv) MacBook-Pro ~ % pip install geopy
Requirement already satisfied: geopy in /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/finalenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: geographiclib<2,>=1.49 in /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/finalenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from geopy) (1.52)
```

The python version for this `Finalenv` is `Python 3.6.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

However, when I try to run my script:

```
import psycopg2

import geopy
```

I get an error that:

```
(finalenv) MacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/s/Desktop/s-project/v2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s/Desktop/s/file.py", line 15, in <module>
    import geopy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Try installing with `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install geopy`. That is guaranteed to match your Python executable with the pip-installed package.

Comment: I see that you're using Anaconda, but then you use `/usr/local/bin/python3`, which suggests it is not the Anaconda related Python executable. Try running just `python3`, without the full path.

Comment: Note: Python 3.6 is past its end of life. It was ended (no security or bug fixes anymore) on December 23, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Anaconda, you can try installing it through `conda` to see if the installation happens on the same folder. Open Anaconda CLI prompt as Administrator. You can try

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

and

`conda install -c conda-forge geopy`.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin/python3` is your OS python executable, not the one used by your virtualenv.

In order to run the script *always* with the python3 on the virtual environment (if it is activated), you can do this:

1. Add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of the file. It will look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psycopg2
import geopy
```

2. Give execution permissions to the file - in your case: `chmod u+x v2.py`
3. And run the file from the shell: `./v2.py`